# Count swear words from tweets in Python

Tags: python, count, word-list

I want to count how many times certain (swear) words appear in my database of tweets, below a simple example. It does not give me the desired output due to the fact that after the "#" is introduced in the text it becomes comments, but I do not know how to solve this.

Thank you.

```
text = RT @JGalt09: #Trump never owed millions $$$ to the Bank of China.  Another hoax from the #FakeNews media.    

word_list = ['fakenews', 'hoax']
swearword_count = 0

text_swear_count = text.lower().replace('.,#?!', ' ').split()

  for word in text_swear_count:
     if word in word_list:
         swearword_count += 1
```

Comment: Your text needs to be inside quotation marks

Comment: Can you explain how to do this when I get the text from a json object into python like this: obj = json.loads(line.replace('\n',''))
text = obj.get('text')
text = text.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '')

Comment: I tried to introduce text = '\"' + text + '\"' but it does not work..

Comment: Well if the text is coming from a json object, then it's already a string. No need to do anything. The problem is that you are using `replace` incorrectly. Using `replace('.,#?!', ' ')` will find the string `.,#?!` and replace it with a space. What you're trying to do is replace **each** of these characters with a space.

Comment: Okay, get it. It works now, thank you!